# Firefox can't connect but chrome can

Tags: apache, google-chrome, http, firefox, hosts

I'm using Chrome and Firefox under Linux (Fedora 22) and today I noticed a strange issue where firefox doesn't seem to be able to connect to "http://friluft.dev", while chrome can.

My `/etc/hosts` contains this line:

```
127.0.0.1 friluft.dev
```

And I can access it fine using Chrome.

Some googling resulted in suggestions like clearing cache, disabling IPV6 etc but have not solved the issue.

What's going on here?

Comment: but `http://127.0.0.1` works?

Comment: Well, apache is configured to respond differently to the hostname 'friluft.dev'. But yes, accessing http://127.0.0.1 does access the apache server.

Comment: I guess you already checked firefox-specific settings for DNS (if something like this even exists..?) and domain name specific proxy configuration (like wpad files)? Has firefox been restarted since you changed your host configuration?

Comment: I have checked different things in firefox and yes I tried restarting.